# What is the graphical representation of Lipschitz continuity?

Tags: real-analysis

I know the graphical represntation for Continuity, Uniform continuity,Absolutely continuity, but I want to know the graphical representation of Lipschitz continuity.

Comment: What are the graphical representations of uniform and absolute continuity?

Answer (score 3):

Take the case of a real function.

If $f$ is Lipschitz continuous with Lipschitz constant $K$, then you have 
\begin{equation*}
\vert f(x) - f(y) \vert \le K \vert x - y \vert~\forall x,y\in\mathbb{R}. 
\end{equation*}
Which means that the slope of the line joining $(x,f(x))$ and $(y,f(y))$ is less than $K$ in absolute value.

That is a way to figure out Lipschitz continuity in a geometrical way.

You can have a similar concept for functions of several variables using norms.